# Xamarin.Forms: how to manage localization of the Share pop-up?

Tags: xamarin.ios, localization, dialog, xamarin.forms, share

I would like to use [SharePlugin](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) in my **Xamarin.Forms** project, but I don't see how to manage the **localization**. I have Android and an iPhone devices, both configured in french.

On Android, the share pop-up is well displayed in french.
But on iOS, the share pop-up is displayed in english.

I've tried to specify languages in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>fr</string>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
  <string>fr</string>
</array>
```

But this didn't change anything.

*Screenshot of the **Share dialog from SharePlugin**:*
[image: screenshot2]

If I use the Share dialog from other apps, like Safari or Facebook, the dialog is well displayed in french.

*Screenshot of the **"default" Share dialog** from Safari*:
[image: screenshot1]

***Would you have an explanation?***

[**Edit**] After having reopened the solution, this works well. 
I think that's because I've edited the `info.plist` outside of Visual Studio: so the change wasn't probably taken into account.

Comment: are you testing with an iOS device or the simulator?

Comment: I've done tests on real devices, for iOS and Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the correct language, we need to query the operating system on each platform to determine which language the user has selected.

What we should do is using a **dependency service** to expose that information in the Xamarin.Forms app and implement it for each platform.

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingResxLocalization/) is official simple. Find `ILocalize.cs` in PCL ,`Localize.cs` in Xamarin.iOS ,and copy them into corresponding folder.(Don't forget change the namespace in the class)

Code in App

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
    {
        // determine the correct, supported .NET culture
        var ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().SetLocale(ci); // set the Thread for locale-aware methods
    }
    MainPage = new FormsApp.MainPage();
}
```

More detail refer to [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/).

My test:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Cole Xia.
I've copied `ILocalize.cs` and `Localize.cs`. I also duplicated the lines 18-25 of `App.cs`. But I get an exception at startup.
Did I forget something?

Comment: @Gold.strike what's the exception info？

Comment: It's `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: Do I need to add the resources files too?

Comment: @Gold.strike No need .resource files are used to define string between different languages .

Comment: Yes, could you say me what's your code in `App.xaml.cs`? Or could you update your sample?

Comment: @Gold.strike try to remove those code in App.cs ,im outside now.

Comment: If I remove this code, I have no longer exception, but the dependency service is no longer initialized.

Comment: @Gold.strike The code in App.cs in my updated answer, it works without exception.

Comment: My apologizes, I had forgotten to copy a line in the `Localize` implementation:

`[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UsingResxLocalization.iOS.Localize))]`

Now the build works well. If I place a breakpoint at the initialization of `Ci`, I see that I recover well `fr-FR`. It's the same thing in `SetLocale()`: `CurrentCulture set: fr-FR`.

But the Share dialog still appears in English...

Comment: @Gold.strike  okay，share your demo ，i will help you to check it.

Comment: I've uploaded the [sample](http://dl.free.fr/nshPk1bo6) with the modifications: I think that we have the same thing...

Comment: @Gold.strike I see you remove the key value in the `info.plist`. Why remove it ? Add it as your first post and it will work well.

Comment: thank you!
I'm not sure, but I think that's because I've edited the `info.plist` outside of Visual Studio: so the change wasn't probably taken into account.
Now it works fine...